# Linux Ubuntu 18.10 menu bar цвет

Tags: linux, ubuntu, цвета

Проблема в следующем. После установки Ubuntu 18.10 поменялся цвет у всех программ у которых присутствует menu bar, см.скришнот. Теперь не видно букв на фоне темного цвета.
Мне нужно поменять цвет текста, как это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прежде всего уточните, к чему относится баг - electron, qt или gtk?

Comment: Gnome? Не пробовали поставить другую тему через Tweak? Проблема сохраняется?